# Excel: Calculate allocation based on Rank

Tags: excel, range, rank

I have a data set with Cost Per Purchase, Volume of Purchase, Budget, Rank and Total Allocation.

I am trying to figure out how to allocate a portion of the Total Allocation based on rank - ideally, the lower the rank (1 is best) the higher the allocation. Is there a formula for this?

In addition, the range of the top 3-5 items (depending on the range between them), should account for 30% of allocation while the rest accounts for 70% (depending on the number of total items). Ideally, budget allocation should higher towards values with a lower cost per purchase - inverse of the current allocation.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/04Ony.png

Comment: Include your input output screenshot in the question.

Comment: how will you determine top 30% shall allocate to 3 items or 5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my attempt , I'm not exactly sure if it fits the need but you can modify the same example for changes.

Basically you can find out the % of some value that you want to allocate

After that you need find out how many ranks fall under 30% like you've mentioned (3-5)

Lastly you can take sum of values for those top ranks and rests based on which you can find out the ratio of the allocation.

[image]

Yellow cells are just headers for the explanation

Orange cells are formula results

Grey cells are your predefined values

Comment: This worked great! The budget allocation is proportion to the rank. However, is there a way to allocate more budget to a lower cost per purchase - inverse of the current allocation?

Comment: @ChaneMay Please edit your question to include the inverse scenario so that I can update the answer accordingly.Also mark this as answer if it resolved your problem.

Comment: Confirming I have updated the question. I will be sure to mark this answered, thank you.

Comment: @ChaneMay I still didn't understand what you want to do , can you edit my example and show me what you want ?

Comment: after recreating the formula(s), I figured I could make the changes through the rank formula (order). Thank you for the help!